# What are the tax implications for my family if someone from China deposits $50k into their account and they transfer to my U.S. account

Tags: united-states, taxes

I have a Chinese wife and we live in China.

She inherited a house and money and we are moving to the United States. We have started transferring large amounts into my personal account in America with no problem until recently.

We had to ask another person in China to wire $50k of our money into my account in the U.S. because china won't allow for my wife to send out more then $50k per year.

When he went to the bank they told him that China had placed a flag on my account not allowing anyone from China to transfer any more money to it.

We still have a substantial amount to transfer so we would like to wire it to various relatives of mine who can then transfer it into my personal account. What if any will be problems for them when it comes to tax time?

Comment: Why are you asking about taxes, when the big issue is China's currency controls?

Comment: Besides, you already said that the PRC has flagged your account to not let any more money be transferred out.

Comment: Consider buying crypto. Then cashing that on a US exchange. TONS of USDT (UST Tether, a coin tethered 1:1 to USD) is used to transfer money from china.

Comment: How can China have any control over your US bank account?

Comment: @jamesqf They don't, but they've told Chinese financial institutions to not allow transfers to that particular US account.

Comment: @mkennedy: Who is "they"?  I could understand the Chinese government not allowing Chinese banks to send money out, but I don't see how they'd have any control about US banks accepting incoming money.

Comment: @jamesqf You're right, of course IF the OP can manage to get the money out of China.

Comment: @jamesqf They're obvious stopping the Chinese banks from sending, not the US bank from receiving.

Comment: @RonJohn He's worried about giving his relatives IRS headaches.  Circumventing Chinese currency controls isn't a US crime but it would look suspicious.

Comment: @LorenPechtel of course.  But you've got to cross the Alps before climbing Mt. Everest, and the PRC is most assuredly **not** allowing him to cross the Alps.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel: But the question has been edited since I made that comment. The original version said that it was the US bank stopping money from being transferred in, which was what I asked about.  Of course China can prevent money from being transferred out.

Comment: Everyone is obsessed with getting the money to the U.S.,the PRC and who is stopping what. The closest someone came to addressing the question is Loren Petchel who actually mentions the IRS issue I am asking about. My bank is solid. this i know. I've talked to them. It's almost another year so most of these problems will go away but I'm still going to try some smaller amounts to relatives and friends this year all under 10k so the issue probably wont arise that I'm worried about.

Comment: "if someone from China deposits $50k into *their account* and they transfer to my U.S. account".  Where is "*their account*" (China or the US)?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.irs.gov/businesses/gifts-from-foreign-person

> For **gifts** or bequests **from a nonresident alien** or foreign estate, you are required to report the receipt of such gifts or bequests **only if the aggregate amount received from that nonresident alien or foreign estate exceeds $100,000 during the taxable year**.  If the gifts or bequests exceed $100,000, you must separately identify each gift in excess of $5,000.

It looks like Foreign Persons can give you up to $100K/year without having to notify the IRS.